# What is the figurative meaning of "butting up against"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [here](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/12/29/asia/china-arctic-influence-intl/index.html):

> In its quest to become a global superpower, China has regularly become entangled in territorial disputes with its neighbors, **butting up against** international law.

What word would you replace **butting up against** with to convey the figurative meaning of it?

Some of guesses are: clashing, colliding, opposing, confronting, defying...

Most definitions I found relate to the literal meaning of "two things being physically close to each other".

Thanks!

Comment: 'Confronting' seems to bridge the literal ... metaphorical gap quite well. 'Challenging' is getting more direct. 'Defying' is stark, contentious.

Comment: In your example you have "against" butting up against "international".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For me "butting up against" in this context has the connotation of the interaction being more incidental to the action than 'confronting'. 'challenging' or 'defying'. There is certainly an element of the perpetrator not recognising the validity of international law and of not caring who they upset but the 'butting up' seems to me to be a consequence of the action whereas confrontation, challenge and defiance seem to be at least part of the reason for taking the action.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For example an industrial worker in the early twentieth century who took a walk on the grouse moors of the English Peak District could be said to have 'butted up against' the laws of trespass but the Mass Trespass on Kinder Scout in 1932 was a deliberate challenge to and defiance of the law and a challenge to the landowners.

Comment: @BoldBen You're saying that the actors in a country are unaware of international laws, when they may have been involved in disputes for many years? If they're consignatories to say UN, they signed up to obey such laws.

Comment: @I'm not saying tht they are unaware of the laws but that the motivation for the act is to pursue a particular course of action rather than to challenge the establishment or attempt to change things. They know that they are infringing rules but choose to ignore them, however sometimes such actions are taken with the primary aim of challenging or defying the status quo and any practical gain is comparatively incidental. My belief is that the action driven by the latter motivation is a challenge or defiance while that driven by the former motivation results in 'bumping up against' the law.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. @BoldBen in your last comment I suppose you meant 'butting up against' the law instead of 'bumping', right?

Comment: Oh, I see, @BoldBen. If I'm not wrong 'bumping up against' would fit this sentence as well as 'butting up against' to describe the unpleasant resulting situation of one ignoring/bypassing an agreement/regulation, but not necessarily implying challenge/defiance as being the underlying motivation for the infringement.

Comment: @RicardoBaptista Correct, I was working on a tablet after I'd gone to bed so it was a typo (or an example of officious autocorrect). However it should have been "butting" of course. Please also note that this is a personal opinion so you can't quote me as an authority in a discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is no stronger than "coming up against". I think "butting up against" comes from joinery: two thick, blunt ends of wood pressing up against each other.

Comment: But [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/butt+up+against#:~:text=butt%20(up)%20against%20(someone%20or%20something)&text=1.,butts%20against%20our%20bushes%2C%20unfortunately.) has << **butt up against** (2) To crash into someone or something >> as well as  <<  (1) To be positioned physically next to someone or something >>. Etymology may inform, but not dictate, meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The intended image is likely to be of butting heads together, like rams or stags fighting.

"China has regularly become entangled in territorial disputes with its neighbors, **clashing with** international law"...

(PS: I should add that I don't find the originally text particularly inspiring, and have a sneaking suspicion that "butting up against" is used incorrectly, as I would expect to see that particular expression in situations, for example, where one building or feature is adjacent to another, as in these random examples:
"the marquee butting up against the building" / "pedestrian esplanade butting up against the building"...)

Comment: [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/butt+up+against#:~:text=butt%20(up)%20against%20(someone%20or%20something)&text=1.,butts%20against%20our%20bushes%2C%20unfortunately.) has <<  **butt up against**  (2) To crash into someone or something >> as well as << (1) To be positioned physically next to someone or something >>.